# Hibernate: How to do a subclass per table with a one to many relationship in xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following table structure:

MyIndicator    IndicatorId, IndicatorType, SomeLinkColumn
IndicatorA     IndicatorId, SomeAValue, SomeBValue
IndicatorB     IndicatorId, IndBSubType, Value

For indicator type A we can only have one, but indicator B we can have multiple subtypes on the same id.
For example
MyIndicator
Id: 1000        Type: A       Link: 999
Id: 1001        Type: B       Link: 998

IndicatorA
Id: 1000        Medicine         Tablets

IndicatorB
Id: 1000      SubType: Food      Value: Peas
Id: 1000      SubType: Bathroom  Value: Toothpaste

These were existing code, so I can't recode everything, the existing should still work. Both indicatorA and indicatorB use to be one-to-one, but now the requirement was for the PK to change on indicatorB to include Subtype.

Hibernate XML mapping currently has 2 <joined-subclass tags that maps to the two subclasses.

How do I make the one subclass be one-to-many?